# Query (2, 2) By default, a year level was expected. No such level was found in the cube.ytd Function In MDX Query Not Work

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, mdx, olap

I use SSAS and SQL Server 2008 R2 and AdventureWorks Database.

I write  this query :

```
Select
ytd([Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Quarter].[Q3 CY 2003]) on columns
From [Adventure Works]
```

and i get this result :

[image]

but when i execute this query  :

```
Select
ytd([Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Quarter].[Q3 FY 2003]) on columns
From [Adventure Works]
```

i get this error :

```
Executing the query ...
Query (2, 2) By default, a year level was expected. No such level was found in the cube.

Execution complete
```

why this query not work ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146039.aspx) : The Ytd function is a shortcut function for the PeriodsToDate [...] .Note that this function will not work when the Type property is set to FiscalYears. How about using the following instead :

```
Select

  PeriodsToDate(
    [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year],
    [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Quarter].[Q3 FY 2003]
  ) on columns

From [Adventure Works]
```